# Not able to use try except for zero division error

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I am using the following code and getting Divide by zero error. I am not sure how to use try/except clause here

```
prelist = [float(b) / float(m) for b,m in zip(prec, res)]
```

Comment: try/except cannot be used inside a list comprehension.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is thrown when you divide by zero.  You are performing a division operation when you create your "prelist" list, which is being done outside your try/except.  Move the prelist creation within try (easier to understand if you use a for loop instead of list comprehension):

```
prelist = []
for b,m in zip(prec, res):
    try:
        prelist.append(float(b) / float(m))
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        prelist.append(0)
```

Another solution is to add an if/else statement within the list comprehension to account for division by zero.

```
prelist = [float(b) / float(m) if m != 0 else 0 for b,m in zip(prec, res)]
```

Comment: I was not using the try/except as part of my code. It was there just for example. I have edited the code now. Thanks for your help.